# Best "architecture" to store lots of files per user on server

Tags: file, server, store

i would like to ask for your opinion and advice.
In my application i need to store files uploaded from user to provide import to database - it could be XML or excel file (.xlsx), i guess max file size about 500kB per file.
There is need to store files because of import to database, which is not done immediately and also because of backup.
I consider scenario about thousands (ten thousands) of users.

Scenario - one user can upload many files to many categories. It means that user can upload file_1 to category 1, file_2 to category_2, but also file_3 to category_2_1(subcategory of category_2).

Generally, there is some kind of category tree and user can upload many files to many nodes.

Because of import application, filename will always contain :
user_code_category_code_timestamp

And my problem is, that i do not know that is the best way to store that files.

- should i have one directory per user -> one directory per category -> relevant files
- should i have one directory per user -> all user files
- should i have one root directory -> all users and all files
- ?

In the best way i mean - there must be application for import, which will list relevant files in category and for relevant user. As i wrote above, there are many ways, so i am a bit confused.
What else should i consider ? File system limitations ?

Hope you understand problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using some kind of a framework? Best case is you use a plugin for it.

The standard basic solution for storing files is to have one directory for all files(images for example). When you save a file, you change the name of the file so they do not duplicate in the directory. You keep all other data in a DB table.

From that base - you can improve and change the solution depending on the business logic. 
You might want to restrict access to the files, you might want to put them in a tree directory if you need browsing in them.
And so on...

Comment: My description of problem might be inexact. Just consider files uploaded from users and application for import. Application for import from excel is written in PHP, XML can be written with some plugins for that etc. - i think that framework is unimportant for my problem.
Business logic is not proper term for this scenario - i am solving problem with data in files, which are parsed and imported to database.
Filenames will be allways unique, whole problem is about how to manage directories and files.

Comment: The username  and subdirectory approach has the following flaw - if the username changes his name, or a category's name is changed - you have to rename the directory.

Comment: yeah, of course ... lets say, that name of user, or category is also always specified with some code, which is uneditable, directories should be named with that code - i think, that there would be minimal problems about renaming ...

Comment: One directory for all files is the standard best solution.
I've implemented such a solution in the past, I used one directory for all files(business reports).  

Any other solution than the standard one - requires additional rules and use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for this question! It was difficult to find answers for this online, but in my case I have potentially 10k's of images/pdfs/files/etc. and it seems that using hashes and saving to one location directory is ideal and makes it much less complicated.

**Useful things to think about:**
1. Add some additional meta data (you can do this in S3 buckets)
2. I would make sure you have the option to resize images if relevant such as `?w=200&h=200`. 
3. Perhaps save a file name that can be displayed if the user downloads it so it doesn't give them some weird hash. 
4. if you save based on a hash that works off of the current time, you can generate non-duplicating hashes. 
5. trying to view all the files at once would hurt performance, but when your app is requesting only one file at a time based on endpoint this shouldn't be an issue.